# Difficulties retrieving image file with file_get_content

Tags: php, string, file-get-contents, image-uploading

I'm trying to fetch a image path and fopen the corresponding image in the tmp directory, but the page only displays a empty img placeholder pic. Thanks in advance

```
public function getImage($path)
    {
        if($result = $this->db->prepare("SELECT filename FROM trips WHERE filename=?"))
        {
            $result->bind_param('s', $path);
            $result->execute();
            $result->bind_result($filename);
            if($result->fetch())
            {

                    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

                    if(!file_exists("C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/" . $filename))
                    {
                         imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
                         imagejpeg($image, "C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/" . $filename);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("C:/xampp/htdocs/webshop/public/img/content/" . $filename);
                    }

                        imagejpeg($image);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "error";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Table retrieve failed: (" . $this->db->error . ") " .$this->db->error;
        }
        var_dump($img);
        return $image;
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to get the contents of `$filename`, not the variable you created with the location of the file, which is `$file`.

Comment: First, it looks like you are trying to get an image based on the path, then you have a useless `foreach` loop, there is only one column being selected, and your foreach overwrites `$row`, but is using `$result`, which is a resource, whereas `$row` actually contained the SQL return.

Comment: Then, after that, you have [imagecreatefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php), which get's the image in to a php resource, but you never output it - for that you need to look at [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) to actually output the image in a format that a browser can understand.

Comment: Could anybody say if  I did it right now :)

Comment: You are still doing `foreach($result as $row)` even though `$result` is a reference to a mysql result set, and you already got the contents with `while($row = $result->fetch())`.  On top of that, you are using a while loop for 1 result.

Comment: For the last time I promise, did you ment like that?

Comment: You still have to assign `$result->fetch()` to a variable to use.  Also, you check to see if the file exists...and if it doesn't, you try and open it anyways? O.o

Comment: in your !file_exists condition section the $image variable is undefined.  It also might be how you are using that function which is the problem and not the function itself